# Vertical scroll value resets on reboot/log-off

Tags: numbers, lines, scrollwheel, vertical-scroll

I have a user that would like to have value for vertical scrolling to be set to a certain number. When they've set the wanted value, it works ... Until they log off or reboot. The odd thing is that the horizontal scroll value will remain to set value even after reboot. I guess it's worth mentioning this is an HP laptop, but the user is using an external USB mouse.

I've tried to update the synaptics driver, uninstall it, remove it completely, check all it's settings for possible overwriting options... No result. Still keeps resetting the vertical scroll value upon reboot/log-on.

As the user is on a domain network, with a company computer, the registry is blocked for any user besides local computer admin OR domain admins, and the only way I've so far found to set scroll value in registry is by logging on as local admin, and then set the value for CURRENT user (aka local admin only, if I understand that function properly).

I am out of ideas, almost. There is only one thing I know of that *could* help, but there is no guarantee. A form of script (VBS/batch) that will run upon user loggin and set the users desired value. Problem is, I am not really familiar with VBS or batch scripts in any large scale, certainly not enough to help myself with this issue.

So, in the end. I am looking for alternate solutions to this pesky problem, or maybe a script that just sets the desired value at user loggin.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, and did a lot of digging to try to resolve it. Most tips on the web suggest to upgrade your mouse driver as some drivers have bugs that result in this problem. In my case I had the latest Logitech drivers already installed, so it didn't help me.

Today I stumbled on the cause of the problem, and hence also the solution: I use the excellent [X-Mouse Button Control](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm) utility. For some reason I had modified its "Lines to scroll using the scroll wheel" setting (Settings > "Scrolling & Navigation" tab), and then forgotten about it. Whenever the program started (I have it auto-start with Windows), it reset the lines to scroll value in the Control Panel mouse settings to "1". Adjusting the value back to the default "3" in X-Mouse Button Control took care of the problem.

Even if you don't yet use the X-Mouse Button Control, this could help you: you could download and install the free X-Mouse Button Control, and make sure the lines to scroll is set to the value you desire in its settings (even if this is the the only thing you would use it for – the utility doesn't by default affect how your mouse works in any way). That way X-Mouse will reset the value to your liking at boot, even if the ultimate cause in your case is, for example, a mouse driver issue.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered already (please mark Ville as answerer if you're still active!) but I wanted to add a picture.

The option to set the amount of lines scrolled is set under the Scrolling & Navigation tab of the main X-Mouse control window:

[image]

In my case, this was set to 3, and had been resetting my Windows value on every reboot/logon.